# Cannot re-apply filters to grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid (`Ext.grid.Panel`) that I need to apply filters to. These filters will be predefined (as opposed to filters you would set by manually choosing them from the grid column dropdowns.)

I have two functions:

```
// Clear filter
function() {
    grid.filters.clearFilters();
}

// Apply filter
function() {
    grid.filters.clearFilters();

    grid.filters.addFilter({
        dataIndex: 'size',
        type: 'list',
        options: ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'extra large'],
        value: ['small', 'medium']
    });

    store.load();
}
```

Applying the filter the first time works perfectly. But, if you call the function to clear the filters and then try applying the filter again, the data is not filtered. I'm not getting any errors or feedback at all.

I'm also not sure if this is the recommended way of adding filters. I've seen examples online where filters are applied to the store directly, but from what I've seen, the grid won't recognize that those filters are in place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do this also. It was part of a bigger function that applied a JSON "grid format object" (containing any number of grid filters, visible columns and a sort column and direction) to a rendered grid panel.

The requirement was that a user needed to be able save the existing gridpanel's visible columns, applied filters and applied sorting into a database with a name and then at later date be able to re-apply these three things to a grid panel to get the same filters, visible columns and sort state by selecting their saved format.

I also did not want to use the store filter because the selected filter options needed to be visible on the gridpanel filter feature UI (the grid filter drop menus) in case the user wanted to adjust them.

Here's an example of a grid format JSON that would be saved by a user:

```
{
"columns":[
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "course",
    "course_room",
    "student_status",
    "start_date",
    "schedule",
    "time_on_course",
    "attendance",
    "this_period",
    "acct_bal"
  ],
"filters":[{
    "field":"student_status",
    "data":{
        "type":"list",
        "value":"Attending"
    }
}],
"sort":{
        "property":"start_date",
        "direction":"ASC"
    }
}
```

Here is the function, the JSON is used as the argument:

```
applyLogFormat: function(format) {
    var log = this.getLog(),
        format = Ext.JSON.decode(format);

    log.filters.autoReload = false;

    // apply the grid filters correctly
    log.filters.clearFilters();
    Ext.each(format.filters, function(filter) {
        var gridFilter = log.filters.getFilter(filter.field);

        gridFilter.setActive(true);
        switch(gridFilter.type) {

            case 'date':
                var dateValue = Ext.Date.parse(filter.data.value, 'm/d/Y'),
                    value = filter.data.comparison == 'gt' ? {after: dateValue} : {before: dateValue};

                gridFilter = log.filters.getFilter(filter.field);
                gridFilter.setValue(value);
                break;

            case 'list':
                gridFilter = log.filters.getFilter(filter.field);
                gridFilter.menu.setSelected(gridFilter.menu.selected, false);
                gridFilter.menu.setSelected(filter.data.value.split(','), true);
                break;

            default :
                gridFilter = log.filters.getFilter(filter.field);
                gridFilter.setValue(filter.data.value);
                break;
        }
    });

    // remove any pre-existing sorting from the grid
    Ext.each(log.columns, function(column, index) {
        if (column.hasCls('x-column-header-sort-ASC') ||
            column.hasCls('x-column-header-sort-DESC')) {
            log.columns[index].setSortState(null);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // show only the specified columns
    log.suspendLayout = true;
    Ext.each(log.columns, function(column) {
        if (column.dataIndex) {
            column.setVisible(Ext.Array.contains(format.columns, column.dataIndex));
        }
    });
    log.suspendLayout = false;
    log.doComponentLayout();

    // set the sorter
    if (format.sort) {
        var column = log.down('gridcolumn[dataIndex=' + 
            format.sort.property + ']');
        column.setSortState(format.sort.direction);
        log.filters.autoReload = true;
    } else {
        log.store.sorters.clear();
        log.store.loadPage(1);
        log.filters.autoReload = true;
    }
}
```

This was all done for 4.1.0

**EDIT:**

I realized there was an important part of the implementation which isn't visible from that function.

Normally the gridpanel `filter feature` menus do not get created until a user physically clicks on one of them. Then they are all created. I suppose this is for memory saving purposes?

Obviously, this function will not work until the filter menus have been created.

To handle this I explicitly create them in the gridpanel's `afterrender` event so that they are available right away. This function will then work even if a user has not clicked on one of the filter menus.

I am using the MVC pattern so I did from the gridpanel's controller, like this:

```
// code from gridpanel's controller
var me = this;
me.control({

    'log': {
        afterrender: function() {
            me.getLog().filters.createFilters();
        },
    },

    // ... other event handlers

});
```

Comment: And you're able to re-apply filters with that method? Everything I try, after I call `grid.filters.clearFilters()` I'm unable to apply new filters. No errors or anything, and logging `grid.filters.getFilterData()` shows an empty array.

Comment: @Arms I have it running right now on the app I am working on. I double checked to make sure that I don't have any other UX applied to this grid. It is a normal grid aside from the `filterfeature` but I am pretty sure that you already have that. What are you passing in the argument? Also are you using 4.1.0 or 4.1.1, I don't know if some functionality was changed on grids that might have broken this.

Comment: @Arms I realized why you may be having problems, see the edit above.

Comment: @Geronimo I am having trouble with grid default filtering. I define default filters as grid.filters, As you say above I cannot figure out how filters will be active unless user click on header menu. I am looking for it for days. I also open a question here maybe you know my solution. my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934186/ext-grid-filtering-default-filter-activation-on-loading

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your grid initialization code

```
filtersCfg.createFilters();

filtersCfg.filters.each(function (filter) {
     filter.setActive(true);
     filter.setActive(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you applying filters to `grid.filters` not to `grid.store`? Ext.data.Store has the following methods `filter()` and `clearFilter()`

Comment: Please see my original question for the reason why I'm applying to `grid.filters`

Comment: Grid will recognize it. Don't worry. We use this approach through out all our wen-apps. Works like a charm.

Comment: Using `store.filter` filters the data for me, but the grid column's filter menu is unaware of the filter, and calling `grid.filters.clearFilters()` has no effect. FWIW, I'm following [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html). Do I need to do any additional wiring between the store and the grid when I apply filters directly to the store?