# Ext grid filtering default filter activation on loading

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, extjs4

I have added default remote filter to grid for column 'hiddenFlag', however it is not active on first loading. When I click column header menu, filter seem to be active however records is now appropriate. I should deactivate and activate it again.

[image: filter seems to be active, however it is not!]

how, I can configure it to be active for the first load also?

```
Ext.define('Ext.migration.CommentGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.commentgrid',            
    xtype: 'grid',
    initComponent: function(){
        filePath = "";
        this.filters = {
                ftype: 'filters',
                encode: false, // json encode the filter query
                local: false, //only filter locally
                filters: [{
                    type: 'numeric',
                    dataIndex: 'id'
                }, {
                    type: 'boolean',
                    dataIndex: 'publishableFlag'
                }, {
                    type: 'boolean',
                    dataIndex: 'hiddenFlag',
                    value:0,
                    active:true
                }
                ]
            };        
        Ext.apply(this, {
            iconCls: 'icon-grid',
            features: [this.filters],
            selType: 'rowmodel',
            columns: [
                {
                    text: 'ID',
                    hideable: false,
                    dataIndex: 'id'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'checkcolumn', 
                    text: 'Yayınlandı mı?',
                    dataIndex: 'publishableFlag'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'checkcolumn', 
                    text: 'Gizle',
                    dataIndex: 'hiddenFlag',
                    filter: {
                        value:0,
                        active:true
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        this.callParent();
    },
    listeners:{
        'afterrender': function(a,b,c){
            //Ext.getCmp()
            console.log("after render", this);

        }
    },
    bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: commentStore,
        displayInfo: true
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the filters are created in the `afterrender` event, e.g.:

```
listeners:{
    'afterrender': function(grid){
        grid.filters.createFilters();
    }
},
```

If that doesn't handle it you can also programmatically set the filters (instead of just using a config). As covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11606415/1062992).

Comment: I thought I try this also, anyway it is working now, thank you. ExtJs is wonderful tool, however, sometimes to find what you need is takes long time and its documentation is not satisfactory and user friendly.